# How to save data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some dynamic data in my `<div>` element. Look at the sample below:

```
<div>345</div>
<div>3245</div>
```

When I click on the div element, the nested value will change.

```
var someVar = $(this).find(div);
    someVar.empty();
    someVar.append("<div>Number has changed</div>");
```

Sample:

```
 <div>345</div>
 <div>Number has changed</div>
```

And when I click again on the div, I need to return the previous value:

```
<div>345</div>
<div>3245</div>
```

Here's the question: **How do I keep this value for returning the number every time I click on the div with changed text inside of it?**

Comment: you can read jquery documentation here : api.jquery.com

Comment: you mean `$(this).find( "div" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need create some `data` attribute store the previous value.The each time click get the data from attribute and restore the current text to attr like this [`data-prev`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).No need to append `.html()` is enought to toggle

**updated**

```js
$('div').click(function(){
var prev=$(this).html();
$(this).html($(this).data('prev'));
$(this).data('prev',prev)
console.log($(this).data('prev'))
})
```

```css
.nested{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>345</div>
<div data-prev="<div class='nested'>Number has changed</div>">3245</div>
```

Comment: Can I push there html-code? Like `<div data-prev='<div>some new data viewed on click</div>'>3245</div>`

Comment: why you need to push the entire element .Any perticular point on that

Comment: Cause I have a data which should disappear on click and then appear on click. Instead of this data will appear the different icons, that are nested inside the entire element

Comment: see my upated answer @LabLab

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery 'data' method.

```
   $( "div" ).data( "number", 1 )
```

Then read it with:

```
  ( $( "div" ).data( "number" ) )
```

Documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/data/